# Dojo spider chart with one series

Tags: dojo

Having trouble spider charting with only one series.

**I tried working off this example:**

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_spidersingle.html

**And set that up here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/FHnwd/72/

**Firebug is throwing:**

Unexpected value NaN parsing cy attribute.

---

I'm completely new to the dojo toolkit. I know I need to addAxis, but it doesn't look like the code from the top URL is working. The axis is starting and ending at the same number despite my trying to set min/max.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Problem has to do with spider charts figuring out the min/max of the axis on it's own. Even when I was using:

chart1.addAxis("Answer 3", { type: "Base", min: 0, max: 250 });

to set the min and max, the spider chart still bombed with only one series.

After playing around with the information in this ticket:

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/14583

I still wasn't able to get this working, I stumbled onto an answer here that basically said as a workaround add series for min and max then remove them after render. So thats exactly what I ended up doing.

```
chart.render();
chart.removeSeries("min");
chart.removeSeries("max");
```

**Demonstrated here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/FHnwd/90/